# Why ggplot use different color scheme on factor type and how to change the default color scheme to "hue" globally?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I meet a problem that makes me very confusing.

I try to convert a column into an ordered factor and plot with `ggplot2`. However, the `ggplot2` used a different color scheme after I converted. The script shows as follows:

```
ta <- data.frame(x=c('b','a','d'),
                 y=c(1.2, 2.4, 3.3))

tta <- ggplot(data=ta, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=x))+
    geom_bar(stat='identity', position=position_dodge())
ggsave(file='p1.png', height=2, width=2.6)
    
ta$x <- factor(ta$x, levels=c('a','d','b'), ordered=TRUE)
## ta$x <- ordered(ta$x, levels=c('a','d','b'))
tta <- ggplot(data=ta, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=x))+
    geom_bar(stat='identity', position=position_dodge())
ggsave(file='p2.png', height=2, width=2.6)
```

- p1.png
  [image]
- p2.png
  [image]

I would like the ggplot2 to use the default color theme as `p1.png` showed even though I convert a column into an ordered factor.

Yes, I could use `scale_fill_discrete()` to specify the color. However, I want to know what is the reason that `ggplot2` use a different color theme and I am looking for a more elegant way.

Thanks for your help.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.9.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.9.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=zh_CN.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=zh_CN.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=zh_CN.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=zh_CN.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=zh_CN.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=zh_CN.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=zh_CN.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[8] base     

other attached packages:
[1] extrafont_0.17 dplyr_1.0.7    plyr_1.8.6     reshape2_1.4.4 ggplot2_3.3.5 
[6] stringr_1.4.0  stringi_1.7.6 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.7        Rttf2pt1_1.3.8    magrittr_2.0.1    tidyselect_1.1.1 
 [5] munsell_0.5.0     viridisLite_0.4.0 colorspace_2.0-2  R6_2.5.0         
 [9] rlang_0.4.11      fansi_0.5.0       tools_3.6.3       gtable_0.3.0     
[13] utf8_1.2.2        cli_2.5.0         extrafontdb_1.0   withr_2.4.2      
[17] systemfonts_1.0.2 ellipsis_0.3.2    digest_0.6.27     tibble_3.1.2     
[21] lifecycle_1.0.0   crayon_1.4.1      farver_2.1.0      purrr_0.3.4      
[25] vctrs_0.3.8       glue_1.4.2        labeling_0.4.2    compiler_3.6.3   
[29] pillar_1.6.1      generics_0.1.0    scales_1.1.1      svglite_2.0.0    
[33] pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

Comment: A discussion about this [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/ordered-factors-now-viridis-colors/15133) and a blog post [here](https://data-se.netlify.app/2018/12/12/changing-the-default-color-scheme-in-ggplot2/)

Comment: You can set `aes(fill = as.character(x))`. This way, your original data type will not be changed and the colors will match your p1.

Comment: There also seems to be no straightforward way to change back the options. See [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4149) , [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/3833) and [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4466)

Comment: Thanks for the post you provide. However, it seems `option` did not work in scripts. I am still looking for a solution could work globally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the intended behavior of ggplot2. If your factor is ordered, their corresponding colors should be ordered, too. By default, colors are ordered using the viridis *sequential* color scheme.
On the other hand, for unordered factors, one wants to have no explicit color order, so here the *categorial* hue color scheme is used instead.
Ironically, this hue palette has also an implicit color ordering which follows the rainbow spectrum.
Finally, it is a little bit subjective to define color ordering at all.

If you want to get the `p1.png` in ordered factors, you could add `scale_fill_hue()` in the scripts as follows:

```
ta$x <- factor(ta$x, levels=c('a','d','b'), ordered=TRUE)
## ta$x <- ordered(ta$x, levels=c('a','d','b'))
tta <- ggplot(data=ta, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=x))+
    geom_bar(stat='identity', position=position_dodge())+
    scale_fill_hue()
ggsave(file='p3.png', height=2, width=2.6)
```

And If you want to globally change the default behavior on ordered factors, you could add the flowing script to `.Rprofile` in `linux`(It did not work, what happened?) :

```
options(ggplot2.continuous.colour="hue")
options(ggplot2.continuous.fill = "hue")
options(ggplot2.discrete.colour="hue")
options(ggplot2.discrete.fill = "hue")
```

Comment: Is there any reference to your answer? Googling this don't seem to have relevant results

Comment: Google for categorical vs sequential color palletes in UX design

Comment: Thanks for the information! However, I don't see how googling that can relate to the color ordering in `ggplot`...

Comment: Now I know the problem, thanks for your help. So I need to add `scale_fill_hue()` in any plots if I want to get `p1.png`.  This seems not elegant if a script has many different pictures (scale_fill/scale_color ...).  Could we change the default color scheme in one script?

Comment: Also, could you add some codes to your answer? So I will accept your answer.

Comment: `scale_fill_hue` **is** already the default `scale_fill`, so no need to call it explicitly, unless you want to enforce it on ordered factors, then you have to do it...

Comment: @cwind what kind of code do you need? I guess you already posted the code in the question, dind'nt you?

Comment: `scale_fill_hue` is not the default if I convert a column to factor. You could try: 
```R
ta$x <- factor(ta$x, levels=c('a','d','b'), ordered=TRUE)
## ta$x <- ordered(ta$x, levels=c('a','d','b'))
tta <- ggplot(data=ta, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=x))+
    geom_bar(stat='identity', position=position_dodge())+
    scale_fill_hue()
ggsave(file='p2.png', height=2, width=2.6)

```
This will get `p1.png`.

Comment: `scale_fill_hue` is the default for character and unordered factors. `scale_fill_viridis_d` is the default for ordered factors.